# Grab Object out of Linq.Enumerable WhereListIterator

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ienumerable, enumerable

im trying to grab a Object(Class) out of a List, depending on a matching string. Im using the .Where function for the list. I have tried replacing it with different casts, but it always throws a InvalidCastException. Has anyone a idea how to directly cast or get the object out of the list?

Exception:
**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[Security.SecurityToken]' to type 'Security.SecurityToken'.**

```
public class SecurityToken {

    public string body = "example";    
}    
public class Tokenizer {

        private static List<SecurityToken> allTokens = new List<SecurityToken>();

        public static async Task<bool> isTokenValid(string token)
        {
            SecurityToken foundToken = (SecurityToken)allTokens.Where(tk => tk.body == token);
            
            return foundToken.body.equals(token);                
        } 

}
```

Comment: Did you tried type after .Where() function First() ? something like (SecurityToken)allTokens.Where(tk => tk.body == token).First(); .

Answer (score 4):

As the error message read, you are casting `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator` which is the result of your query `allTokens.Where(tk => tk.body == token);` to a `SecurityToken` which is wrong, a better approach is using [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0);
but looking at your code, all you need is to check if any item meets a condition, so I suggest using [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0).

```
return allTokens.Any(tk => tk.body == token);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Where` returns a collection not a single object. You need to change code like below:

```
SecurityToken foundToken = allTokens
                            .Where(tk => tk.body == token)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

return (foundToken !=null);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have done this before and by doing that, i only get a NullReferenceException.